# Why is this answer bad but this one awesome?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/10201560) audit, and I would like to understand why.

The answer is for a (9 month old) question with zero votes and low views. Additionally, there is no other answer, so this is definitely no "I want to answer a famous question to get some rep" type of answer.

Lets have a look at it:

> The ajax form is repeating the post. It sends the first one, and then the second, etc. If you put an alarm() on the callback, you'll see it repeating as many times as you sent the data.
>   A solution could be e.stopImmediatePropagation();
>   Read [more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708691/prevent-multiple-click-events-firing-jquery/12708948#12708948) in another answer.

The answer was deleted for being *link only*. When I look at this answer, I See:

1. An explanation of the problem:

   > The ajax form is repeating the post. It sends the first one, and then the second, etc.
2. Help on verification:

   > If you put an alarm() on the callback, you'll see it repeating as many times as you sent the data.
3. A possible solution:

   > A solution could be e.stopImmediatePropagation();
4. *further information*:

   > Read [more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708691/prevent-multiple-click-events-firing-jquery/12708948#12708948) in another answer

The linked answer however reads:

> Have you tried: event.stopImmediatePropagation?
>   I believe it is what you are looking for:
>   http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

This answer has **19** upvotes, but - as far as I can see - is even more link only than the one in question.

I would love if someone could explain to me why the one is bad while the other apparently is awesome.

Comment: Short RTFM answers like that only get awesome when it has been around for a while and vetted by other programmers to be the correct answer.  Which it did.  Google usually helps bring them in.  Not the kind of help we can count on anymore btw, their new algorithm isn't too happy about the kind of Q+A we produce these days.  They improved it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tend to agree with you that the answer is definitely not link only. Without the link it conveys a possible solution. I wouldn't have flagged it as link only.

The answer it self is worth to be down voted as it is more of a guess than a solid deduction of possible bugs. For that the question lacks enough information. I close voted the question for that reason.

With that said I'm not sure how we can restore the world order on this review. I don't think the answer should be undeleted, but if it was I would edit it.

I can only say: you have hit bad luck, sorry about that.

Comment: Time is a huge factor here.  The linked post is 3 years old and the audit post is 3 weeks old.  Things change with time, especially how the community evaluates posts.

Comment: Thank you @psubsee2003, I think you have an important point here